# I got "TabError" and tried 8 methods I thought would work. But still can't work it out

Tags: python

Edit1: I got the `KNN` module by using the command `pip install KNN` and the command worked normally, showing the module was installed. When I use the command again, it returns this:
`Requirement already satisfied: KNN in c:\users\Username\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.0.0)`

Code:

```
import KNN
print(KNN.__version__)
```

Problem: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Editor: VS code

OS: Windows 10

What I tried and got:

1. delete all tabs and spaces in the code, make sure there’s no tabs and spaces in my code.
2. Use ‘convert indentation to tabs’ function in VS Code editor.
3. Use ‘Convert indentation to spaces’ function in VS Code
4. Use ‘delete indentation from content’ function in VS Code

Each of these methods gets the same error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\Username\Documents\python\test3", line 1, in <module> import KNN File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\KNN.py", line 24 print(sortedDistIndicies[i]) TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

5. Search for ‘Space’

Get: there’s no spaces used for indentation. And still the same error.

6. Search for ‘\t’

Get: No ‘tab’ used in this document. And still the same error.

7. Use `autopep8 -i test3`   command.

Get:

The command `autopep8 -i test3`  completed normally. But when I run ‘test3’ it still gives the same error:
 `Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\Username\Documents\python\test3", line 1, in <module> import KNN File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\KNN.py", line 24 print(sortedDistIndicies[i]) TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

8. Use  (Str + A) and press Shift + Tab

Get: Still same taberror.

That’s all I tried and got for now, thank you for reading my post.
Is there anything I can try to fix this?

Comment: The error is in the package you've imported, not your own

Comment: where did you get the `KNN` module from

Comment: @rioV8 Hi! I got this module by using `pip install KNN`.

Comment: it is a Python 2.x file, you have to edit the `print` statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what the error message says:

```
KNN.py, line 24 print(sortedDistIndicies[i]) TabError
```

Looking at the file at line 24 is a Tab character to indent 8 spaces.

Replace the Tab with 8 spaces, and while you are there also remove all the trailing Whitespace (Ctrl+K Ctrl+X in VSC)